# how can I provoke Bison to insert a token?

Tags: bison

I'm trying to implement a simple basic, but I'm afraid the operation of Bison is not clear for me. To implement a 'while' loop the examples I found uses the construction below (or similar):

*while '(' expression ')' statement   { $$ = opr(WHILE, 2, $3, $5); }*

But actually there are two hidden jumps I ought to assign tokens to. I mean as follows:

```
while                             // no token assigned
( expression )                    // take appropriate sequence of tokens
jump back if not met              // insert a conditional jump token - a jump to expression checking
statement                         // take appropriate sequence of tokens
jump unconditionally              // insert a token to jump to expression checking
```

However neither the expression length, nor the statement length is not known, I can record the address the 'while' keyword is entered, so last jump can be calculated. But what will provoke Bison to insert a conditional jump token?

Comment: But are you interpreting the code right when parsing it? Or do you compile it into a sytax tree to execute them after a intermediate compilation phase?

Comment: I am just compiling. When all the source is compiled to tokens, then is downloaded into a micro controller. The micro interprets tokens and executes.

Comment: Take a look at my edit, maybe you will understand in a better way how I make it work usually.

Comment: Jack, many thanks for exhaustive answer. I will have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do exactly but a while statement is often "compiled" into something like

```
loop:
.. evaluate condition ..
JUMPC out
.. body ..
JUMP loop
out:
```

What I usually did with interpreters I wrote is to have a phase that solves all labels after the parsing so that just jumps and labels with dummy names are emitted while parsing the syntax tree, then it's possible to caculate the address of each label and adjust all of them, so for example you would have

```
510-580 .. evaluate condition ..
590 JUMPC 820
600-800 .. body ..
810 JUMP 510
820
```

This can be done easily by using also a simple `std::map` to store all the labels so that after generating the parsing tree you just go through the code, computes all addresses of labels (which disappears from the AST) and then insert correct addresses in the jumps.

Just to make clearer what I usually do:

```
//parser.y

while_stat:
  KW_WHILE T_LPAREN exp T_RPAREN block { $$ = new ASTWhileStat($3, $5); }
;

//ASTWhileStat.h

class ASTWhileStat : public ASTNode
{
  ASTNode *m_condition;
  ASTNode *m_body;

public:
  ASTWhileStat(ASTNode *condition, ASTNode *body) {
    m_condition = condition;
    m_body = body;
  }

  ASTWhileStat(const ASTWhileStat &other) {
    m_condition = other.m_condition;
    m_body = other.m_body;
  }

  ASTWhileStat &operator= (const ASTWhileStat &other) {
    if (&other != this) {
      m_condition = other.m_condition;
      m_body = other.m_body;
    }

    return *this;
  }

  ASTWhileStat *clone() {
    return new ASTWhileStat(*this);
  }

  u8 type() {
    return 0;
  }

  void populateSymbolTable() {
    m_condition->populateSymbolTable();
    if (m_body)
      m_body->populateSymbolTable();
  }

  void generateASM()
  { 
    u32 sCounter = ASTNode::labelCounter;
    u32 eCounter = ++ASTNode::labelCounter;
    ++ASTNode::labelCounter;

    printf("while%u:\n", sCounter);
    m_condition->generateASM();
    printf("NOT\n");
    printf("JUMPC while%u\n", eCounter);
    m_body->generateASM();
    printf("JUMP while%u\n", sCounter);
    printf("while%u:\n", eCounter);

    ++labelCounter; 
  }
}
```

Now, in my case I generate ASM text output of a lower level language because I have then another parser which parses this sort of ASM code into binary but you can just join these two steps. What happens in the ASM parser is the following:

```
label:
  STRING T_COLON { ASSEMBLER->addLabelHere($1); }
;
```

That does:

```
void Assembler::addLabelHere(string str) {
  printf("[ASSEMBLER] Added label %s at %u\n",str.c_str(),curPos);
  labels[str] = curPos;
}
```

This because the assembler knows the internal state of the assembling code and knows the current offset from the beginning of the program.

At the end of assembling phase all labels are solved:

```
bool Assembler::solveLables()
{
  map<string,u32>::iterator it, it2;

  for (it = jumps.begin(); it != jumps.end(); ++it)
  {
    it2 = labels.find((*it).first);

    if (it2 == labels.end())
    {
      printf("[ASSEMBLER] Unsolved label \"%s\"!\n", (*it).first.c_str());
      return false;
    }

    u32 address = (*it2).second;
    u32 pos = (*it).second;

    printf("[ASSEMBLER] Solved jump at %u with address %u\n",pos,address);

    memcpy(&code[pos], &address, sizeof(u32));
  }

  return true;
}
```

As you can see I brutally copy the address of the jump inside some bytes that I reserved when I assembled JUMP calls.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is I wonna do, but have no idea about the mechanism, how to reserve place for token represented in your example in line 590.

Comment: That is I wonna do, but have no idea about the mechanism, how to reserve place for token (in your example line 590). At first pass enough to leave place for it and insert during second when calculating labels. Due to termination of 'while' structure I can prescribe to insert the last jump represented in your example in line 810 - but have no idea how should I recognise the expression/statement border to insert some gap for conditional jump token (in your example line 590). What part of the source will warn Bison: this is the point where some gap or token should be inserted.

Comment: I would like to know what do you output from the parser (eg. what you are assigning to yylval with `$$ = ` in your parsing rules.